# Is it secure for the path between CloudFront and EC2 to be over HTTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, https

I have a CloudFront distribution set up where the user connects to my domain via the CloudFront distribution and it determines if their request goes to my S3 bucket or my EC2 instance.

In this case, the connection between the user and CloudFront is HTTPS, and there is the green padlock in the browser.

My concern is that the connection between CloudFront and EC2 is now over HTTP. I tried changing the origin policy to HTTPS, but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't need a load balancer as it is just one server.

I also don't think I can install the CloudFront certificate on my EC2 server because I don't have access to the private key of the CloudFront certificate.

I also can't use a LetsEncrypt certificate on my EC2 instance because it requires a domain name and my EC2 instance is just an IP address.

Everything works right now, but I'm just concerned that it is insecure. What if someone types their password into my site? Wouldn't it only be encrypted when being sent from the user to the CloudFront distribution, and then it would be unencrypted and be plaintext when traveling over the internet between CloudFront and EC2? Couldn't this be logged by an intermediaries along the way?

Is there a solution to this, or is it not a problem? I'm a bit confused because I see several people say it's fine to use an HTTP origin policy between CloudFront and your EC2 instance, but I'm not sure how that could be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many aspects to answer this.

1. CloudFront endpoints are deployed in so-called *Edge locations* where the traffic enters the AWS global infrastructure. Any traffic between CloudFront and your EC2 should only be routed over AWS infrastructure and not through any 3rd party operators.

   **Update**: [AWS Global Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/) page says: *All data flowing across the AWS global network that interconnects our datacenters and Regions is automatically encrypted at the physical layer before it leaves our secured facilities.* I.e. even if some of the interconnects are actually traversing 3rd party networks they are always encrypted so your plaintext HTTP should never be visible by that 3rd party operator.
2. You already trust AWS with your data - you run your EC2, manage your SSL certificates for CloudFront, etc, so at the same level you probably trust their network as well. I would say the risk of snooping your plain-text traffic inside AWS is pretty low, although not non-existent.
3. You can create [self-signed SSL certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) on your EC2 and CloudFront will happily accept them for reaching your EC2 origin. That way you can have HTTPS all the way. This self-signed cert will only be used for the *CF <-> EC2 traffic*, not for your *User <-> CF traffic*, so no issues with *invalid certificate* warnings.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that if I have a CloudFront edge location in some country (let's say Japan) and my EC2 instance is in Ohio, then Amazon owns every single link the packet travels across from Japan to Ohio? Every router, modem, and cable? Even the undersea cables?

Comment: @RyanPeschel maybe they don't own every single wire, quite likely they lease some of it, but as they say on [AWS Global Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/) page: **"All data flowing across the AWS global network that interconnects our datacenters and Regions is automatically encrypted at the physical layer before it leaves our secured facilities."**

Comment: Oh, so it's still being encrypted between CloudFront and EC2, just at a lower-level? If this is indeed the case, then you would only need HTTPS between CloudFront and EC2 if you didn't trust Amazon? So what is the recommendation here? Should I even bother with the self-signed SSL certificate then? I'm a small site and nothing is too mission-critical (although there are passwords being sent)

Comment: @RyanPeschel Many companies would choose to use HTTPS all the way, and that's fair enough. Especially if they need to comply with certifications, auditors, handling personal data or credit card details. Many other sites that don't do any of that will be fine with HTTPS to the edge and then HTTP to the origin.

Comment: Okay, I think I might look into a self-signed certificate then. I might as well learn how to do them anyway, and I think I'd just personally prefer if everything was HTTPS. Even though the chance is low, I just prefer the peace of mind.

Comment: @MLu it may not be correct to assume that the *"AWS global network that interconnects our datacenters and Regions"* includes all of the CloudFront edge locations.

Comment: @RyanPeschel CloudFront actually [does not allow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html#ssl-certificate-expired) the origin server to use a self-signed certificate.  CloudFront will return a `502 Bad Gateway` error.  To do otherwise would create a large security hole, since anyone could create a self-signed cert and use it to create an impostor origin (after compromising DNS).  You need a legitimate cert on the origin, which you can get for free -- from ACM if the origin uses an ALB, or from Let's Encrypt, otherwise.

Comment: You’re right, I stand corrected. CF doesn’t allow self-signed certs, I confused that with ALB/ELB that does. That’s how we do end to end HTTPS. So Ryan the correct way is: *CloudFront with ACM cert -> ALB with ACM cert -> EC2 with self-signed cert. *